# Width of page is bigger than I set it to?

Tags: html, css

I set my header div to width: 100% but a horizontal scroll bar appears and I can scroll a lot more to the right of the page, which is completely white.

Comment: Your navbar width and positioning are going to cause you problems.

Comment: Your navbar is positioned 500px from the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because your navbar has a width of 90% of page but is left 500px.

So if page width at 100% equals 1000px and navbar is 90%, that means navbar is 900px wide and then placing it 500px left means its 400px over the width of the page which causes the scrollbar to appear.

Comment: So I should set navbar width to 100%? Sorry, but I'm not following entirely.

Comment: It all depends on how you want the navbar positioned. If you want it to be on the right side I would remove max-width and left and then make it display: inline-block; and float: right;

Comment: Or if you don't like floats you could remove max-width and left. Add width: 100%, display: block; and then text-align: right;

Comment: I did that, and thanks, that's how I wanted it to be. I used float but now there's another problem. A blank small space above the header appeared. It all looks rather weird. Here's a screenshot of it http://i.imgur.com/bM4OIDx.jpg

Comment: Can't be sure without looking at elements in console but I believe its because of the top: 30px in #navbar style. Try removing that.

Comment: That didn't do it. I honestly can't tell what else it could be.

Comment: @CRover let me try to reproduce it. Which way did you use? The float or the text-align?

Comment: @CRover if you open your console and highlight the elements individually they will highlight in the browser and from there you should be able to see on each element in different colors how padding and margining and height\width are applied. I think padding is green and margin is red. This will tell you where that space is coming from.

Comment: The float. Let me update the code in the post so you can have exactly the same one.

Comment: As weird as this may sound, the space disappeared all of a sudden. I've changed some stuff but I don't know exactly what it was that caused it. It now looks better. Anyway, thanks a lot for all the help!

Comment: @CRover Great, glad you figured it out. If its not too much trouble would you mind accepting this as the answer if you felt it helped you. trying to earn rep for site privileges. Thanks!